# If $|f(z)|\leq |g(z)|,$ then we conclude that

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are entire functions and $g(z)\neq 0,\forall z\in \mathbb C.$  If $|f(z)|\leq |g(z)|,$ then we conclude that

(a) $f(z)\neq 0,\forall z\in \mathbb C$

(b)$f$ is a constant function

(c) $f(0)=0$

(d) For some $c\in \mathbb C, f(z)=cg(z)$

My attempt:-

Since, $g(z)\neq 0,\forall z\in \mathbb C.$ So, $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is analytic.

$|f(z)|\leq |g(z)|,\implies |\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}|<1$. An entire function cannot be bounded. By Lioville's Theorem $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=c$ for some $c$. So, (d) is the answer. But in the answer key. It is given that (a) is the only correct answer.

Comment: (d) is correct. (a) is not correct, as $f=0$ the constant function is a counterexample.

Comment: Your solution is correct, the answer key is just wrong.

Comment: Why does $g(z)\ne 0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$? It can be $f(z)=g(z)=0$ for some $z$, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is perfectly fine. Note that $f(z)=e^z$, $g(z)=2e^z$ is a counterexample for b),c) and  $f(z)=0$, $g(z)=2e^z$ is a counterexample for a).

Answer (score 0):

Let the two entire function be $$f(z)=u_1(x,y)+iv_1(x,y)$$ and $$g(z)=u_2(x,y)+iv_2(x,y)$$

Given that $g(z) \neq 0 \forall z \in  \mathbb{c}$, so $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is also entire.

Now $|f(z)| \leq |g(z)|\implies |\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}| \leq 1 \implies \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is bounded entire function.

So by Liouville's theorem $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is constant.

i.e., $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=c$(say), where $c$ is complex constant

$\implies f(z)=c g(z)$

So **option $4$ is correct.**

Here we are unable to say any thing particularly about $f(z)$ and $g(z)$.